# Почему не работает код игры «угадай число»?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>guess game</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var user_guess;
var random_number;
var finished = false;

function guessing() {
    random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    while (!finished) {
        user_guess = prompt("I'm thinking of a number in a range from 1 to 100. Guess a number!");
        finished = checking();
    }
}
function checking() {
if (isNaN(user_guess)) {
        alert("It is not a number! Write a number!");
    return false;
    }
if ((user_guess <1) || (user_guess > 100)) {
    alert("It is not a correct number! Choose between 1 and 100! ");
    return false;
}
if (user_guess > random_number) {
    alert("It is higher than mine number!");
    return false;
}
if (user_guess < random_number) {
    alert("It is lower than mine number!");
    return false;
}
    else {
    alert("You got it!");
    return true;
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Может быть просто забыли вызвать функцию `guessing`?

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли вызвать функцию `guessing`. Нужно добавить строчку

```
guessing();
```

в конец тега `<script>`. Как-то так:

```js
var user_guess;
var random_number;
var finished = false;

function guessing() {
  random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  while (!finished) {
    user_guess = prompt("I'm thinking of a number in a range from 1 to 100. Guess a number!");
    finished = checking();
  }
}

function checking() {
  if (isNaN(user_guess)) {
    alert("It is not a number! Write a number!");
    return false;
  }
  if ((user_guess < 1) || (user_guess > 100)) {
    alert("It is not a correct number! Choose between 1 and 100! ");
    return false;
  }
  if (user_guess > random_number) {
    alert("It is higher than mine number!");
    return false;
  }
  if (user_guess < random_number) {
    alert("It is lower than mine number!");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You got it!");
    return true;
  }
}

guessing();
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @AndyG, не за что :)

Answer (score 0):

Добавь `guessing();`

```
guessing();
function guessing() {
...
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!